# Calling multiple html page from php consecutively

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am not well versed in php. I tried different answer from stackoverflow but was not successful in solving the problem.

I got a HTML form with a submit button. After submitting I call a php script and which in turn calls an executable file which runs some algorithms on the submitted data from the html. At the end I echo the result of the analysis through the php.

```
<?php
$ex=shell_exec("...");
if($ex == "Run Successfully\n"){

echo"<html>
<meta http-equiv= refresh content='0.1;URL=--.txt'>
</html>";
}
?>
```

Till this works fine but my algorithm takes 30-40 sec to run and all that time my original html page remains in screen which looks like nothing is happening there. So I created a new html page with a progress bar animation. Now I want to show the progress bar while the executable is running and when the result is available I want to replace the progress bar page with the result page as before.

I tried `echo file_get_contents("waiting.html");`

`header ("location: waiting.html");`

But none of them works as I planned. All the time they are coming up only after the executable finish working and not before that.
If someone can help me with some suggestion I shall be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just `include` the file instead of `shell_exec()` in included file assign the result to `$ex` variable.

Comment: @Manibharathi I am using shell_exec() to call the executable file which has the algorithm. But I want to show the `waiting.html` before the execution starts and then again want to show the result after it is available.

Comment: PHP didn't support like this so need to use js ajax calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where jQuery and AJAX would work very nicely. What you could do is start with the loading animation, and use jQuery to call the php file with the shell_exec with ajax. Once the ajax is .done(), then you can replace the text with the results. If you need me to clarify, just let me know.

However, if you don't want to use AJAX, PHP is run line by line. Therefore, you would want to put your progress bar before the shell_exec. This would mean that you would not be able to use header location since headers have already been sent.

Edit (AJAX Example):
This would be a quick example of how to make this happen.
Create two php files:
**progress.php**

```
Load jQuery
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
url:'algorithm.php',
type: 'post',
cache: false,
success: function(data) {
//Replace with how you want to format the page
}
});
});
</script>
Loading Bar
```

**algorithm.php**

```
<?php
$ex=shell_exec("...");
if($ex == "Run Successfully\n"){
die('{"status":"success"}');
}
?>
```

Now you don't have to use json as an output. You can also have html output. Let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I dont know ajax/jQuery, so if this can be done with PHP or javascript then it will be prefarable for me. But if its not possible without AJAX, then can you explain me a bit further, may be with some code snippet or some code links ?

Comment: thanks for your explanation, with some reading on Jquery and AJAX and with your example, I finally created a working solution.